# Chart is not Displaying in visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, reporting, visualforce-charting

I'm not getting the chart in visualforce page so please kindly help

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Potential__c" extensions="dynamic_report" sidebar="false" >

<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

                <apex:outputLabel >User</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:selectList multiselect="false" size="1" value="{!SelectedUser}">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Names}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>



            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:commandButton value="Get Report" action="{!getTeamMembers}" /> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Project Wise">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Summaries}" var="summary" style="width:50%" id="Chart">
        <apex:column headerValue="Project" value="{!summary.Project_Name}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="Count" value="{!summary.Quantity}"/>
     <!--   <apex:column headerValue="Total" value="{!summary.total }"/> -->
    </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock title="chart">
        <apex:chart height="1600" width="1600" data="{!Summaries}">
            <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="Quantity" title="Count" minimum="0" margin="10" maximum="120"/>   
            <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="Project_Name" title="Stage" id="stg"/>           
            <apex:barSeries orientation="vertical" axis="left" xField="Project_Name" yField="Quantity" colorsProgressWithinSeries="true"  /> 
        </apex:chart>
    </apex:pageBlock>


</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class dynamic_report {

    AggregateResult[] ag;
    public string SelectedUser {get;set;}
    public Summary[] Summaries { get; set; }
    public string qry;
    public list<Potential__c> opp_list {get;set;}
    public string filter =  'as';

    public dynamic_report(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

    public AggregateResult[] User(){
        qry = 'SELECT Project_Name__c,Count(id) Quantity FROM Potential__c';
        if(SelectedUser != null){
            qry += ' WHERE Owner.name =: SelectedUser';
        }
        qry += ' GROUP BY Project_Name__c';
        AggregateResult[] results = database.query(qry);
        Summaries = new List<Summary>();
        for (AggregateResult ar : results) {
            Summaries.add(new Summary(ar));
        }
        return results;
    }

    List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();

    public List<selectOption> getNames(){
        options.add(new SelectOption('None', '--None--'));
        for(User u : [SELECT name FROM User ]){

            options.add(new selectOption(u.name,u.name));
        }
        return options;
    }

    public pageReference getTeamMembers(){

          User(); 

          return null; 

    } 

    public class summary {
        public Integer Quantity {get;set;}
        public string Project_Name {get;set;}

        public summary (AggregateResult ar){
            Quantity = (Integer) ar.get('Quantity');
            Project_Name = (String) ar.get('Project_Name__c');

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Do you see data in your table?  Have you tried changing the size of the chart

Comment: i'm getting data in table earlier chart size was even lesser i made it 1600 but still i'm not getting anuthing

Comment: Try putting a `!summary.` in front of each of your field names as in `xField="!summary.Project_Name"`. Also 1600 x 1600 pixels is far too large. Think about what your screen resolution is. That's clearly not the source of your problem.